# Does iteration work on sequence diagram?

Tags: uml

please help me to resolve my doubt.
I already known that iteration works on system sequence diagram. But I am not sure is it worked on sequence diagram.

Comment: I'm sorry but it's very difficult to understand what is your question? What do yo mean by system sequence diagram? What do you mean by "Does work"? If it's possible to present on such diagram? Something else?

Answer (score 0):

It is allowed to draw a loop on a sequence diagram, see example below. The term "system sequence diagram" is not a UML term.

[image]